# How to add Account name to a contact in Dynamics 365

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, alexacrm-toolkit

I am using Alexa-php-toolkit for Dynamics 365 https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit, using this I can successfully create new contact but I can't add an account name with the contact, when I try I get this error:

> Notice: Property accountid of the contact entity cannot be set in ../vendor/alexacrm/php-crm-toolkit/src/Entity.php on line 263.

Here is my script.

```
<?php
//URL: https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit
/**
 * Use init.php if you didn't install the package via Composer
 */
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../vendor/alexacrm/php-crm-toolkit/init.php';
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'includes/db.php';
$db         = new DB();
$options    = getAuth();
$serviceSettings = new Settings( $options );
$service = new OrganizationService( $serviceSettings );
$accountId = 'a2536507-018d-e711-8115-c4346bac0a5f';
// create a new contact
$contact = $service->entity( 'contact' );
$contact->accountid = $accountId;
$contact->firstname = 'Test';
$contact->lastname = 'Contact12'; 
$contact->jobtitle = 'Business Analyst';
$contact->mobilephone = '1002345679';
$contact->fax = '9902345679';
$contact->emailaddress1 = 'john.doe1@example.com';
$contact->address1_line1 = '119 Cambridge'; 
$contact->address1_line2 = 'Apt 22';
$contact->address1_city = 'Houston';
$contact->address1_stateorprovince = 'TX';
$contact->address1_postalcode = '77009';
$contact->address1_country = 'US';
$contactId = $contact->create();
echo $contactId; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this line of your code in a question:

```php
$contact->accountid = $accountId;
```

First, the parent account on a contact is saved in the `parentcustomerid` field that is a [special lookup field that can store link to both account or contact entity](http://www.powerobjects.com/2017/07/28/customer-fields-comes-to-dynamics-365/).
The fields `accountid` and `parentcontactid` help to handle this in background, but are not generaly available. You need to work with `parentcustomerid` field.

Second, another problem when working with lookups (foreign keys) is you need to pass entity type (table name).

The correct code might look like this:

```php
$accountRef = $client->entity( 'account' );
$accountRef->ID = $accountId;
$contact->parentcustomerid = $accountRef;
```

or

```php
$contact->parentcustomerid = new EntityReference( 'account', $accountId );
```

Those examples are taken from the [issue list](https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit/issues/25), adjusted, but not tested. I hope it is working example, not functionality request.